# Proof that $\lim (x_n)^{1/k}=(\lim x_n)^{1/k}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove $\lim (x_n)^{1/k}=(\lim x_n)^{1/k}$ having already proved it for $k=2$.  Even experimenting with $k=3$ I'm getting stuck.  If we call $x=\lim x_n$ then I have

$$|(x_n)^{1/3}-x^{1/3}| \cdot \left|\frac{(x_n)^{2/3}+x^{2/3}}{(x_n)^{2/3}+x^{2/3}}\right| = \left|\frac{x_n-x-x_n^{2/3}x^{1/3}+x_n^{1/3}x^{2/3}}{(x_n)^{2/3}+x^{2/3}}\right|$$

In the proof for $k=2$ I didn't have this positive term in the numerator to deal with.  I know that I could choose $|x_n-x|<\min\{\varepsilon,x/2\}$ which would imply that $x<2x_n$ but this seems to suggest a way to replace $x$ rather than $x_n$ which seems unhelpful.

Comment: Your title and body disagree. (The $1/n$ in the exponent in the title is probably the error.)

Comment: Do you know that $x^{1/k}=e^{\log(x)/k}$, and that the exponential function and the natural logarithm are continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not complicate things, just use the fact that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent then $a_nb_n$  also is and $\lim a_n b_n=\lim a_n \cdot \lim b_n$.

Suppose that $\lim ((x_n)^{1/k}) \neq (\lim x_n)^{1/k}$ and take both sides to the power of $k$ and use above written law and then conclude.

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest approach. +1. We also need to cover cases when $\lim x_{n} ^{1/k}$ does not exist and show that in these cases $\lim x_{n} $ wouldn't exist.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think that it is not perhaps, but that it really is the simplest approach.

Comment: Agreed! But can't edit my comment after 5 mins are gone. :)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So what? You did not do any damage  to me or to yourself with that comment.

Comment: Don't worry last comment was intended as a joke. And I have incorporated your proof into one of my blog posts just now. I will add a reference to your answer in my blog post.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No problem, you can do that freely.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but don't we still have to show that $\lim (x_n)^{1/k}$ exists?